# Issue with changing lookup object and then updating its field

Tags: soql, lookup

I have 3objects Suivi_TDM__c, Opportunity and Simulation__c.
Suivi_TDM__c is related to opportunity via lookup relationship via field Ref_PC__c found on object Suivi_TDM__c.
Opportunity is related to Simulation__c via lookup relationship via field Simulation_Offre__c found on object Opportunity.

Now I want to change the lookup field Simulation_Offre__c on opportunity and replace it with the ID_Simulation__c found in suivi_TDM
And then, update the new Simulation_Offre__c of suivi_TDM to Active.

Can you check if the code below is good.

```
List<Suivi_TDM__c> SuiviTDMList = [SELECT Id, ID_Simulation__c FROM Suivi_TDM__c 
                            WHERE Id =: oppIdSet];

if(!SuiviTDMList.isEmpty()){

    for(Suivi_TDM__c suivi_TDM : SuiviTDMList ){  

       //change Simulation_Offre__c of an opportunity with that of suivi_TDM
        suivi_TDM.Ref_PC__r.Simulation_Offre__c = suivi_TDM.ID_Simulation__c;
        Database.update(suivi_TDM,true);
        // change the status of the new Simulation_Offre__c to 'Active'
        suivi_TDM.Ref_PC__r.Simulation_Offre__r.Statut__c = 'Active';
        system.debug('opp new  values'+ suivi_TDM.Ref_PC__r.Simulation_Offre__r.Statut__c );

    }

}
}
```

Comment: What do you expect if there are two Suivi_TDM__c with one parent opportunity? Which ID_Simulation__c use?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update object through relashionship. You can create temporary list of object and then update it:

```
List<Suivi_TDM__c> SuiviTDMList = [SELECT Id, ID_Simulation__c, Ref_PC__c 
    FROM Suivi_TDM__c WHERE Id =: oppIdSet];

map<id,opportunity> oppToUpdateMap = new map<id,opportunity> ();
map<id,simulation__c> simToUpdateMap = new map<id,simulation__c> ();

for (Suivi_TDM__c suivi_TDM :SuiviTDMList) {
    if (Null != suivi_TDM.Ref_PC__c) {
        oppToUpdateMap.put(suivi_TDM.Ref_PC__c, 
            new opportunity( id = suivi_TDM.Ref_PC__c, Simulation_Offre__c = suivi_TDM.ID_Simulation__c));

        if (Null != suivi_TDM.Ref_PC__r.Simulation_Offre__c) {
            simToUpdateMap.put(suivi_TDM.Ref_PC__r.Simulation_Offre__c, 
                new simulation__c( id = suivi_TDM.Ref_PC__r.Simulation_Offre__c, Statut__c = 'Active'));
        }
    }
}

update oppToUpdateMap.values();
update simToUpdateMap.values();
```

Unfortunately it's not clear what to do if there are two Suivi_TDM__c with one parent opportunity. Map will update latest opportunity only.